# CopyFiles too late

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I need to copy files as soon as my MSI is clicked. I'm using CopyFiles function at the minute but it is not doing it quickly enough. Do I need my own custom action or is there a way to move it before any UI is shown?

Thanks

Comment: Can you ellaborate why you need to do this?  What's the purpose of the files?  MSI's aren't suppose to make any changes to the system prior to InstallInitialize or after InstallFinalize.

Comment: I have a requirement to copy an ini file and reg file to c:\\TEMP at the very beginning. It can be easily done in InstallShield, I thought WIX would support this too

Comment: Just because something is easy to do in InstallShield doesn't mean that you should do it in InstallShield.

Comment: I need more information about what you are doing with this INI and Reg file to give you the optimal design solution.

Comment: The customer can edit the ini file and reg file to names they want, etc as they are provided separately from the MSI. I copy them to the C:\TEMP folder an call the info from there. I have my custom actions adding the .reg file to the registry and I get my product name from the INI file. These are not used by all customers, just a few and I have to be flexible for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the requirement has been poorly defined and designed.  Here's an example of what you should be doing:

I have a customer who sells a product directly (retail) and indirectly (through value added resellers).  His application is extensible in that  he, or his VAR's or their end user customers have requirements to be able to extend / modify / override the MSI with such attributes as:

1) UpgradeCode

2) ProductName

3) License Agreement

4) Icon

5) Configuration Files

6) Digital Certificates

My customer wrote a wizard UI in C# the guides the user through all this and I wrote a library that interacts with MSI using the WiX DTF library (Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller).   The result is an a utility that completly encapsulates the process in which the MSI is transformed into a variation.

This is how Symantec Antivirus works as well.

With some dev time, you could guide your user into building an MSI with updated ProductName and Registry table entries.  The resulting MSI wouldn't need any custom actions and would still follow all applicable Windows Installer best practices.

Comment: Thanks I will propose this, but I now have it working to the requirments. Thanks Christopher

Comment: Chris, is this Wizard open source? I have faced such requirements too, but to a limited degree so that I could read the info from the MSI from an INI file and reg file located in the same folder as the MSI source file. The users could then customize information inside these two files and we were done. I had some problems finding the right "source folder", but that was resolved. Don't recall the solution at this stage unfortunately :-(. This "folder dance" could be different for different operating systems and msi engine versions though. Your "transform solution" sounds better.

Comment: Hi, I still have to follow this procedure but i'm hitting a wall as I created a custom action to copy the files from TARGETDIR. But TARGETDIR is not initialized until InstallInitialize and this is still too late. Please can someone help me..:(

Comment: My customer wrote the UI and I wrote the library.  Either way, it's purpose built for his exact needs and would need to be rewritten for your needs.  FWIW, I only spent a few hours working on the library. C#/DTF really makes it easy.

Comment: Hi Christopher, Going to try your solution and see how it looks and if it would work for us. Where would you suggest starting, do you know of any good websites on this? Thanks

Comment: Shoot me an email and I'll send you a little sample.

Comment: @Glytzhkof looks like we are trying to achieve the exact same thing. Are you going to attempt Christophers solution?

Answer (score 4):

Anything done with reg files and ini files can generally be embedded and done inside the MSI instead. This is hugely superior since the MSI file will then feature built-in rollback support if the installation of the MSI is aborted.

Installshield provides its own setup.exe launcher file which is not actually an MSI file at all, and it is this file that puts such temporary files in place on the system. It's a legacy feature from before the MSI days, and it essentially allows poor MSI design above anything else.

As Chris points out an MSI file should not perform file operations and system changes until its install sequence is launched (the actions between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize in the InstallExecuteSequence inside the MSI).

I would recommend putting the ini file information in the IniFile table, and the registry information in the Registry table. Are you running EXE files as part of your installation sequence?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your advice but I have explained above that I have to do it this way. Not the best option with WIX but I have to meet requirements.

Comment: Point on about rollbacks. This is a very important requirement otherwise why even bother using MSI?  I use msi temp tables and views a lot at my day job where I dynamic author the MSI and then let MSI handle the heavy lifting.  This technique is best for situations where the data isn't known until install time and my other answer (Transform)  is best when the information is known prior to running the MSI (build time).