# Copy files before installation begin in wix

Tags: c#, wix, installation, wix3.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CopyFiles too late](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053404/copyfiles-too-late)

I have a problem in wix directory structure.

Actually i want to copy some files in temp folder and play with these files in my custom action before the real installation is start.My question is that there is a way to copy files before the installation begin.

I think wix copy files during installation.

I am new to wix and there is no good tutorials available on net.

Comment: I can't conceive of a reason why you'd *require* that the files that are part of your installation haven't already been copied into place before executing your custom action, and it'll be a lot easier to do, since WiX is already pretty good at copying files onto the target filesystem.

Comment: Because i want to copy files with my custom actions not with wix.Actually i convert my setup project installer to wix.In my setup project all the work is done in custom actions,I want to reuse it instead of writing again with new logic of wix

Comment: there are plenty of good tutorials, it's just not easy and best to learn MSI before you learn WiX.

Comment: What's the point of converting to WiX if you want to do everything with lots of custom actions? Using such approach, your solution isn't WiX — it's something different; in such approach WiX is more an obstacle whereas it's supposed to be a helper.

Comment: Wix have some juicy features with respect to UI.Wix have much control on UI over Setup project.
Wix setup easily compile without Vs and more other features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because i want to copy files with my custom actions not with wix.

This is one of the biggest mistakes you can make in your installation project. Windows Installer (the underlying technology behind all the installation) can do several things incredibly well, and copying files to the target system is one of those.

If you look at your own question in more detail, you'll notice the variance: you'd like **to copy the files before the installation (that is, the process of copying files among everything else) starts**.

If you'd like to migrate to WiX, but pull all custom actions with you and reuse all of them, I don't see any point in such a migration. In order to get all out of WiX, use the WiX-way anywhere you can.

So, this is what I would do if I get the task like this one day:

- sit down and browse your current installation project and note each action it actually does
- when this list is completed, filter it leaving those actions it ***should*** actually do
- find out what actions of that list could be done with the standard tools of WiX (Windows Installer supports naturally)

  - BTW, file copying is among those
- find out what actions which left could be done using standard WiX extensions, like IIsExtension or UtilExtension
- if there are still actions left (I expect this list to be quite small), write custom actions for those

  - make sure your [custom actions are data-driven](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/9/13/Zataoca-Custom-actions-should-be-data-driven)

Hope this gives you some hints for further investigation.